# Swift String operation not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to read the string from a Label and remove the last character form it.

This is how I am trying:

```
@IBAction func del(sender: UIButton) {
    let str = telephone.text!;
    let newstr = str.remove(at: str.index(before: str.endIndex))
    telephone.text = newstr;
}
```

When I run, I get an error:

```
"String" does not have a member named "remove"
```

Can someone help me figure out the problem?
Just started learning swift :(

Comment: In Playground I can compile your code and it works just as expected. Try using `let str = "Test"` for testing purposes. Btw, you don't need to use `;` at the end of a line.

Comment: I tried "Something" as text and the IDE still gives the same error :(

Comment: `remove(at:)` mutates the receiver and expects a *variable*.

Comment: what version of swift r u using? in swift 2.0 try this
var name: String = "Dolphin"    
name.removeAtIndex(name.endIndex.predecessor())

Comment: Try `var str = telephone.text!`.

Comment: when I ran $ xcrun swift -version i get version 1.2 of swift

Comment: @ssdesign: Which Xcode are you using? Swift 1.2 is ooold, the current version is Swift 3.1 and comes with Xcode 8.3.

Comment: I am updating my Xcode right now.... seems like I am not using the latest one.

Comment: Updating Xcode did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove(at:)` mutates the receiver which must therefore be a *variable*
string:

```
var str = telephone.text!
str.remove(at: str.index(before: str.endIndex))
telephone.text = str
```

Alternatively use `substring(to:)`, which returns the new string
instead of modifying the receiver:

```
let str = telephone.text!
let newstr = str.substring(to: str.index(before: str.endIndex))
telephone.text = newstr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
let idx = str.index(before: str.endIndex) // compute the index
let s = str.substring(to: idx)            // get the substring
```

Comment: Get the requested sub string.

Comment: But why an extra variable for the index?

Answer (score 0):

`remove` is defined as follows:

```
public mutating func remove(at i: String.Index) -> Character
```

See the `mutating` modifier? That means it mutates the instance on which the method is called. In your case, the instance is `str`, a constant. Since constants cannot be mutated, the code does not compile.

And since `remove` returns the removed character,

```
let newstr = str.remove(at: str.index(before: str.endIndex))
```

here `newstr` will not be storing the string with the last character removed.

You should rewrite the method like this:

```
telephone.text!.remove(at: telephone.text!.index(before: telephone.text!.endIndex))
```